# How to set MouseBinding in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to call click command on TextBlock, and i do that like this

```
<TextBlock Text="New Project">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=NewProject}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

And that is work, but i want to do the same in ItemsControl, so

```
    <ItemsControl Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}" Grid.Row="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ClickableTextBlock}" >
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=OpenTasks}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And that doesn't work, command is not called. How to do that?

Comment: where is the property `OpenTasks` defined? it's part of an item or of the whole viewmodel? Also you can try viewing the ***Output*** window to see if there is any error notified there.

Comment: OpenTasks is part of viewmodel and in output doesn't appear any errors. OpenTask property works fine, only inside this ItemsControl doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit `DataContext` inside `ItemTemplate` is the current data item. But the `OpenTasks` is not part of each data item. As you said in your comment, it's part of your viewmodel. So in this case you have to set some explicit source with `RelativeSource` for the Binding. It helps walk up the visual tree and target the source you want. In this case you need the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl`. The code should be like this:

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenTasks,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
              MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
```